# running an android app on IntelliJ

Tags: android, mobile, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 9 setup successfully including all the Java SDKs necessary and the Android SDK too.

I created a simple project and to run it, I went to the Configurations to setup a virtual device.  Device was created successfully but when I'm trying to run the app, nothing happens.  The console shows the following:

```
Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd MyAvd0 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

but no devices are shown... Am I missing something?  The JetBrains wiki doesn't say anything special as far as I read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 9 is too old and [doesn't support new Android SDK versions](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-62526). You can find workarounds in the issue linked above, but it's recommended to use the latest IDEA version.

Long SDK path with spaces may also introduce problems.

Comment: infact that was the problem - path with a space :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read and followed the guide on [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up) - it'll lead you through all the steps necessary.  A quick check to see if your device is being recognised by your computer is to go to the DOS prompt, assuming you have your paths set up correctly, and type 'adb devices' - this will either show you that the device is connected - mine looks like this

```
martyn@ubuntu:/$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
353406EE22EB00EC        device
```

Comment: i fixed it by installing the Android SDK in another place